# is there a jquery shortcut for triggering an input

Tags: jquery

I have to add an input with a name of "btnupdateprice" that I first have to dynamically insert it into the page (hidden of course) and then trigger it. Is there a way to do this without inserting it into the page like the following? A shortcut perhaps?

```
$("input[type='hidden'][name='ProductCode']").before('<input type="image" border="0" name="btnupdateprice" src="blank_image.gif" style="display: none;">');
$('input[name=btnupdateprice]').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Why don't you just call the function assigned on this button click?

Comment: @BrunoLM: maybe the context within the handler is important (for one reason..)

Comment: when the button is clicked it uses the form button name and other hidden inputs to construct a post request. Sorry if I am not explaining it 100% correctly.

Comment: @jAndy -- perhaps, but you should be able to simply adjust any query/form parameters as necessary.  Not knowing what is being called client- or server-side makes it hard to answer, but I would think that you'd only have to add whatever information necessary to inform the server what button was clicked -- perhaps just adding `btnupdateprice` to the form parameters would be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the reverse flow using [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/), and the shorthand function [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
$('<input type="image" border="0" name="btnupdateprice" src="blank_image.gif" style="display: none;">').insertBefore("input[type='hidden'][name='ProductCode']").click();
```

If you don't want to add it to the page you can just remove the `.insertBefore(...)` part.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, not that your are wrong cause you are not, but I was hoping for a way to do that without actually inserting a input element. Even if it was only for a instant between when its inserted and then triggered. Perhaps its not possible.

Comment: Maybe you can clarify why exactly you can't call directly the `form.submit()` function ? (ex: `$('form')[0].submit()`)

Comment: Although this does not answer my question exactly it does provide a partial answer to my question (shortcut) so I will have to give this one to you. Thx

Comment: cause there is another input button in the form.